# Access object outside of class

Tags: java

This is probably a noob question since I'm just starting Java. I made a Person object with its own class, and a main class that creates the actual object (it's an array too). However, I'm now trying to access this object in another class. How would I change the current object to be able to be used outside of the Main class?

Main.java

```
package me.chris.pizzacost;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    static Person[] people;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Pizza Cost!\nTo start, how many people are in on this order?");

    people = new Person[scan.nextInt()];

    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Type their names, pressing ENTER between names.");
    for (int x = 0; x<people.length; x++) {
        //System.out.println("ran");
        people[x] = new Person();
        people[x].name = scan.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("hit the end");
    }
  }
}
```

Person.java

```
package me.chris.pizzacost;

public class Person {
  static String name = "blank";
  static double cost;
}
```

Comment: You... wouldn't? It would work fine. Also, the `name` and `cost` variables shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: @AlexisKing how would I access it then?

Comment: Pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: @kirbyquerby I'm sorry, I recently started Java and don't know exactly what you're saying. How would I, say, change the name of people[2] in another class? What would the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

```
static String name = "blank";
static double cost;
```

shouldn't be static:

```
package me.chris.pizzacost;

public class Person {
    String name = "blank";
    double cost;

}
```

create a setter the main class too:

```
 public class Main {
 //etc...
      public static Person[] people; //put the declaration here. as a class member. 
      public static void setName(int element, String name){
           people[element].name = name; //set the name of the specified element in the array.
      }
```

in any other class, just call `Main.setName(personID, "The Name");` In STATIC CONTEXT

Or just make `people` a `public static` class member, and just call `Main.people[element].name = "Whatever name"` (Example:)

```
package me.chris.pizzacost;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static Person[] people; //put the declaration here. as a class member.    

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   // static Person[] people; (get rid of this)

    System.out.println("Welcome to Pizza Cost!\nTo start, how many people are in on this order?");

    people = new Person[scan.nextInt()];

    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Type their names, pressing ENTER between names.");
    for (int x = 0; x<people.length; x++) {
        //System.out.println("ran");
        people[x] = new Person();
        people[x].name = scan.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("hit the end");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the static part, but why would a setter help me access the variable elsewhere? I can set it just fine, but say I want to see what the actual object has. How would I do that?

Comment: @Chris the setter helps you set the variable if you want the array of people to be `private` (Other classes can't see it directly, by calling Main.people) And can you clarify what you mean by seeing what the object has?

Comment: Eclipse gives the error "Illegal modifier for parameter people; only final is permitted" when I add "public static" to the beginning of the creation of "people"

Comment: @Chris I see what you mean, just put `public static Person[] people;` outside of the main method, as a class variable, I'll update the answer.